# Counting the amount or Post Parameters a site has

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

My site currently gets multiple post parameters(date1, start1, end1, date2, start2, end2, etc.) depending on how many textboxes were enabled in the site, it gets the parameters from. My task now is to insert those values into the database, which has proven to be very interesting.

My plan is to count the amount of parameters, divide them by 3 and insert them by using a for-loop or something along those lines. Unfortunately i have found no way on how to count the amount of parameters. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you try `$count = count($_POST);`

Comment: Uhm ... what about `count($_POST)`?

Comment: ok thanks for that. it sounds so logical really, but i really hadn't thought about the one method to count arrays with...

Comment: Glad that worked. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count an array, `count()` function can be used. `$_POST` `$_GET` etc, are always meant to be an array, unless it is not set.

So, to get the count of variables posted, use `count();`

```
$count = count($_POST);
```

That might raise a warning if the $_POST array is not set. So add an `isset` check.

```
if (isset($_POST)){
$count= count($_POST);
//more codes
//more codes again
}
```